# getting range of values from excel with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to read a range of values from Excel. This is the code I use.

```
//  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'test.xlsx';
//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}


$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
echo "A1 is: ".$cellValue."<br>";


$dataArray = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->rangeToArray(
        'A1:C1',     // The worksheet range that we want to retrieve
        NULL,        // Value that should be returned for empty cells
        TRUE,        // Should formulas be calculated (the equivalent of getCalculatedValue() for each cell)
        TRUE,        // Should values be formatted (the equivalent of getFormattedValue() for each cell)
        TRUE         // Should the array be indexed by cell row and cell column
        );

echo "number of items in array: ".count($dataArray);
```

For some reason the count of `$dataArray` is just 1, although I am retrieving a range that should match 3 items. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, it is an array of arrays. A 2d array. Each array in 2d array representing a single row. If the query were `A1:C3`, than it would return 3 primary arrays.